# Assignment that doesn't change original value if it's null

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a shorthand for this code:

```
bool value1 = true;
bool? value2;

if(value2 != null) //or value2.HasValue
{
    value1 = value2.Value;
}
```

Something that should not change original value of `value1` if it's null. Something like a [null-coalescing assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) but for right hand being null not left hand. E.g. something like:

```
value1 (some assignment operator)= value2; //should evaluate to "true" since value2 is null
```

Comment: `value1 = value2 ?? value1;` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
value1 = value2 != null ? value2 : value1;
```

or

```
value1 = value2 ?? value1;
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool' in your first example.